# SPOnline migrating data from 1 Site Collection to another Site Collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, data

We currently only have UAT Site Collection which has some data. Data includes Lists, Images, Documents, and Pages. The Lists have some lookup columns.

We would provision PROD Site Collection in time and we are wondering how best to migrate the Data? For on-prem, I believe you can use the Content Database, but since we don't have access in SP Online, how best to migrate all the data mentioned above?

Comment: Have you considered writing PowerShell script to transfer data?

Comment: Yes, but we would like to keep things such as versioning if possible. I'm not sure if that is achievable through scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  Migration Tool for same
you can use tool for migration like "Sharegate"(Trial version)
For more info

http://www.slideshare.net/benjaminniaulin/sharegate-sharepoint-migration-tool

Comment: Thanks S.P. Unfortunately,  I don't think we'll try 3rd party tools because it costs money, which budget is currently tight.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using Metavis Migrator tool and its really good. http://www.metavistech.com/product/migrator-sharepoint

Comment: Thanks Nirav. Unfortunately, I don't think we'll try 3rd party tools because it costs money, which budget is currently tight.

Comment: In that case you would have to write your own migration tool. :)